# How to estimate a tempo by looking at a melody

Tags: theory, harmony

There is an exercise in a Harmony book by Aldwell & Schacter, where you are asked to figure out the correct meter and to estimate a "suitable tempo" for a snippet of melody, in other words, figure out what kind of tempo the piece is originally written in just by looking at the notes and the meter.

I tried to go back and find an answer how I could estimate the tempo, but I just don't seem to get it. How could I figure out a piece's tempo by simply looking at the melody without any tempo markings? Should I focus on the note values? Or on the shape of the melody?

Comment: Welcome! Although we could talk about the idea in the abstract, it would probably be easier if you could post an image of the exercise.

Comment: Could you add the page and/or exercise number? I have an old edition of A&S and would like to look at the exercise (assuming it's in my edition). Also, adding to your post an image of the exercise would be helpful.

Comment: Also, just a preview: Any estimate created this way is going to be very much an *estimate*. People can come to widely differing opinions of the "right" tempo for a piece (and feel very strongly about it)—just look at the history of recording and talking about Beethoven's symphonies. But there are some things that lead us to a certain broad tempo range. More than note values, the rate of chord changes will be one of the biggest factors. And various instruments (including voice) have various technical challenges that might create "too fast" or "too slow" tempos.

Comment: To be honest this does not seem like a particularly deterministic exercise. We all know for example how much slower Beethoven symphonies are usually played compared to what Beethoven demanded – this should be proof enough that a tempo estimation is a very subjective thing. So in the end – just imagine the melody and choose a tempo that feels right.

Comment: Expand the exercise to modern music and all bets are probably off. I've seen (fan-made) sheet music for music with quarter note = 200 bpm or more that still has 16th notes ("The Battle of Lil' Slugger", I'm looking at you). Nastier still is classical music that uses 64th notes at quarter note = 120 bpm or more (glaring at Elgar's Pomp and Circumstance March No. 2 in A Minor right now).

Comment: Very much a 'non-question' as tempo often has little bearing on what it's written in. 'Andante - 76-108 bpm' is vague enough to prove that. Just sing the melody, and guess a comfortable speed from that.

Comment: Thanks for comments guys! I will post an image of the exercise here as soon as I get the book back in my hands, but I think it was the second to last exercise of Chapter 3, rhythm.

Answer (score 2):

Your rephrasing of the problem makes it harder than it actually is.  Finding "a suitable tempo" is not the same as finding the original tempo.  There are many suitable tempos for some music, only one of which can be the "original" tempo.

> Should I focus on the note values? Or on the shape of the melody?

Yes.  Another consideration is the harmonic rhythm.  For example, consider two pieces in 4/4 meter.  In one, there is no more than one chord in each measure.  The other has a different chord on every quarter note.  The fastest suitable tempo for the first is probably too fast to be suitable for the second.

If the exercise doesn't specify the harmonization, then there's even more room for subjectivity (and for creativity).  For example, if you have an ascending scale in the melody, you might treat some notes as non-chord tones, or you might harmonize every note.  The former approach yields a slower harmonic rhythm so it admits a faster maximum suitable tempo.

For an example of a suitable tempo that is wildly different from most people's expectations, see

As another example, I clocked four recordings of Handel's *Messiah* overture, all by baroque specialist ensembles and conductors, between 72 and 96 beats per minute.  (By contrast, Otto Klemperer conducted it for a 1964 recording at 42 b.p.m.)

Comment: Finally someone's found a good tempo for the 'Moonlight' Sonata. It's worth noting that Beethoven notated it in cut common time. Glenn Gould also often found 'unusual' tempi. I don't always agree with his choices, but they were always interesting..

Comment: At least in modern music, harmonic rhythm is no indicator of "suitable" tempo. I sporadically listen to heavy metal with chord changes every 8th note at quarter note = 180 bpm or more. I once transcribed the melody of the *Aggretsuko* OP and found it to be quarter note = 208 bpm, yet change chords every quarter note somewhat consistently.

Comment: @Dekkadeci that certain musical styles can use a faster harmonic rhythm doesn't mean that harmonic rhythm is entirely useless as a guide to suitable tempo.  In any event I doubt that Aldwell and Schachter are setting exercises that have anything to do with heavy metal.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind, musicians *disagree* on tempo choices all the time. I have an edition of Bach's *Inventions* with a chart of tempi from various previous editions and the metronome markings vary considerably.

In past eras note values were a basic indicator of tempo. To cite a source: Rameau's *Treatise on Harmony* discusses it in the section on meter.

To put that into perspective a sarabande normally uses a slow tempo in triple time whereas a courante normally uses a fast tempo in triple time. The sarabande might be found using half notes for the beat, but the courante might use quarter notes for the beat. Ex. Handel's *Suite in D Minor, HWV 437.*

So, assuming this is the exercise you're talking about...

[image]

...the Beethoven example uses quarter notes for most of the rhythm. By the thinking of Rameau (not necessarily appropriate for Beethoven) you can say it shouldn't be obviously slow - it's not using half and whole notes primarily, and not too fast - it isn't using eighths or sixteenths primarily, so moderate or allegro tempo might be appropriate.

I don't want to give you the answer, but I did guess the meter and barline placement correctly, and my sense of a moderate tempo was pretty close to the tempo indication of the original. So I think Rameau's teaching seems to bear out even for a Beethoven work.

---

FWIW, a thematic index of some kind will help find melodies. I used...

https://bestclassicaltunes.com/ThematicByComposer.aspx?composer=Beethoven

...to find the Beethoven tune after completing the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

I guess we're talking about this?   Tricky, aren't they!

(Yes, I know this is a comment not an answer.  But we want to see the picture without jumping through hoops, don't we?)

[image]

Comment: If that's Aldwell & Schachter chapter 3, pretty sure you've got the right thing. You could double down by addressing the question! (Which, yes, is a pretty good one—there's a lot that goes into guessing an "appropriate" tempo, whether consciously or intuitively.)

Comment: Somehow, all but the Haydn excerpt got away with being at an Allegretto tempo or slower, and the only reason why I assigned the Haydn Allegro or faster is because I've seen and listened to too many Allegro or faster Haydn works with 8th-note runs.